# Plot graph in swift without using third party libraries like core-plot

Tags: ios, graph, swift

I want to plot pie-charts and bar-charts in swift , without using any third party libraries ? Any help would be great

Comment: Have you achieved your desired output without using third party library?

Comment: yeah, we can. Using CALayer and coregraphics

Comment: Have you created any sample? Do you have any reference to github repo?

Answer (score 0):

Core Graphics can be used to draw line graphs , bar graphs etc . I mainly used the CALayers to create specified graphs .